# VARCHAR(MAX) SqlParameter Output Size for Visual Studio 2003

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures

In newer editions of .Net I can pass -1 for the output size for `VarChar(Max)` columns, but in Visual Studio  2003 I get the following `System.ArgumentException`:

> Invalid parameter Size value '-1'.  The value must be greater than or
>   equal to 0.

What should I specify as the size for a `VarChar(Max)` column in Visual Studio 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
,SqlDbType.varchar, 8000)
```

or

```
,SqlDbType.text)
```